# Modify the HTTP status code after PHP has finished generating a response

Tags: apache-2.2, php, http, redirect

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure apache to modify the HTTP status code of a response after it has been generated?

Basically, I have a script running under multiple host names that redirects users to a dynamically determined location using a 302 status code, which is generated by the script itself (i.e. a PHP script which sets a 'Location' header).  What I want to do is change the status code from 302 to 301 for just one of the host names, while keeping the rest using 302, and I want to do it at the server configuration level so that the script need not be modified.

I've had a look around the apache manual and found mod_headers, but it doesn't seem to be able to modify the status code of a response, only the headers that follow it.  Can anyone tell me if there is there a way to do this, or am I stuck with my only option being to modify the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite to accomplish this, i.e with the following example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site2.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ site2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Placing an .htaccess under the hostname you want to redirect will make this work. You can also modify your vhost configuration as well. Don't forget `RewriteEngine On` if not set already.

Comment: mod_rewrite is only able to act pre-response (i.e. before the script returns a response), isn't it?  I need to modify the the status line post-response (i.e. after the script has returned a response).  To my knowledge this is not possible with mod_rewrite - or am I wrong?

Comment: I don't think this is possible at all actually...at least with Apache. Nginx has some config magic to make this work.

Comment: I was beginning to suspect this might be the case.  Thanks for your input.